# Mobilefirst 7.1 CLI + Ionic Android Build Failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I've searched a lot on the internet and find a lot of question/solution about it but I can't find a solution which works for me.

I made an application with mobilefirst and ionic and when I try to run it on the emulator or on my smartphone I get an error which is :

```
Error: BUILD FAILED
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second

D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
```

I'm using Java 8 and ant 1.9.6.

Thank you

Edit : I've changed the Java version from 8 to 7 and the error is still there...

There is the result when I change Java version :

```
D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova>mfp cordova run
Searching for list of Devices...
? Which device id do you want to target? 5da2ac45 - Qualcomm RIL 1.0
Cordova config.xml currently configured with:
        mfpServerUrl: http://192.168.78.240:10080
        mfpServerRuntime: backend
MFP Command: mfp cordova run --platform android --target "5da2ac45"
Building and Deploying android application prior to running...
Error: BUILD FAILED
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android_SDKs\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds

D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen

D:\work\MobileFirstProjects\projects\TestCordova>java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: please use java 7.

Comment: how you set your java environment?ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: Yes I've set ANDROID_HOME to my android sdk root folder and then in PATH I add ANDROID_HOME/tools and ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools

Comment: but your error represent  may be ANDROID_HOME not set correct way.

Comment: I understand but everything is correctly set...

Comment: What is your Cordova version? What is your cordova-android version?

Comment: My cordova version is (with cordova -v) 6.0.0 and my cordova-android version is (with cordova platform version android) 3.6.4

Comment: @OuldBouamamaNicolas, can you try without Ionic and see that you are able to build the app?

Comment: @IdanAdar I've tried with cordova alone and I had the same problem. Do you me to try just with mobilefirst ? Without cordova

Comment: There is no such thing "without Cordova". MobileFirst is always with Cordova. I'll not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @IdanAdar Ok thank you. I don't know what to do about that problem... Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the instructions in this blog post, providing details on how to create an Cordova app in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 that is integrated with Ionic: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/19/developing-ionic-apps-with-mobilefirst-7-1/

Essentially:

1. Create an MFPF Cordova project
2. Create an Ionic project
3. Copy over the Ionic `www` assets

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link,

https://github.com/csantanapr/mfp-ionic-templates   It will help you to integrate ionic with mfp 7.1 version.

**Essentially:**

Create cordova project & give the ionic project link over there like,

```
    $ mfp cordova create myapp -p ios,android -t ~/Downlaods/mfp-ionic-templates-master/tabs
    $ cd myapp
    $ npm install
```

Its worked for me.

Comment: can you share your sample here